# Proxy classes for Android to use SOAP web service?

Tags: java, android, soap, wsdl

I want to connect to a **SAOP web service** (WFC) in a **android app**. Therefore I want to **generate and use classes**.
SOAP is set on this project - so we can NOT use a REST Service.

Hey it is 2013 and there is nothing else than using the kSoap approach 
and to do the xml parsing. There must be a more convenient way to do so (for very large web services!)
(Apache Axis or Jax-WS on android?)

*What is the state of the art way for this?*

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried Soap Enabler [link](https://code.google.com/p/android-soap-enabler/). But this project did not work - after 5 hours the sample worked. But the generation fails on my WCF services (complex types?). Then I tried kSoap but there all XML parsing has to be done myself.@DjHacktorReborn

Comment: is there really no one who had this problem?

Comment: Yeah, I have the same problem. I tried using jaxws in an Android project, but it does not seem to work what so ever.